# Force user to reload page

Tags: javascript, ajax, client-server

Background information:

1. I have JavaScript that makes an AJAX request.
2. I am using a version URL parameter to make sure that when a page loads it gets the latest version of the JavaScript file: `/path/to/file.js?v=20160511`

That problem I need to solve now is when I make a change to the data that is returned by the AJAX call (I assume this is considered an API break), and the JavaScript file (client). My first thought would be to somehow force the user to reload the page when I release a change to the API. What is a good process to make sure the client and server stay in sync?

Comment: You can send notifications from server to client by the help of websocket connection. By handling the notification in client side, you can force page reload. 
Alternatively you can do polling to server from client that asks 'should I update' everytime, when server side update the flag to change, clients will be forced to reload.

Personally, I strongly recommend the first solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Uğurcan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400515/u%C4%9Furcan-%C5%9Eengit)'s comment and [Hullu2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967642/hullu2000)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189053/244826), I added two things to my current implementation. The total necessary items are:

1. The JavaScript referenced in page has a version URL parameter to make sure that when a page loads it gets the latest version of the JavaScript file: `/path/to/file.js?v=20160511`
2. The API call returns a JSON response with an API version string
3. The JavaScript checks the API response version string against a local variable. If they don't match, it calls `window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to trigger a ''location.reload();'' on the client.